# Reset Spinner on click button in another fragment/view

Tags: tabs, fragment

I´m getting started in Java/Android development. I´m making a survey type application with several tabs and with swipe navigation. (Based on SDK/ eclipse example).

I have a fragment (tab) inflating a view with some spinners, and I need to make a reset button  in another fragment which reset all spinners to position 0.

The fragment with the spinners.

```
public class Viagem extends Fragment
{


 public Spinner spinLinhaO;


    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_viagem, container, false);

     final Spinner spinLinhaO = (Spinner) view2.findViewById(R.id.spinnerO1);

        // with the adapter to populate it 

 }
```

The fragment with the button.

```
    public class Inicio extends Fragment
{ 

    @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 

        View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_menu, container, false);


        final Button button = (Button) view3.findViewById(R.id.buttonInq);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view3) { 
         Viagem.spinLinhaO.setSelection(0); //this does not work
 }
```

May you help me how to solve this??